# GCM framework parameters and GCM Registration ID

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

During a registration request from a subscriber app to the GCM server, the app includes a senderID/projectID and its context. And my guess is when the GCM framework on the client receives the app request, it prepares a request by adding the app package name (uniquely identify the app), device ID (uniquely identify the device), the senderID.

1. Are there any additional parameters added by the GCM framework?
2. Is there a relationship between these parameters and the registration ID (or is the registration ID generated randomly)?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help. If you look at table 1 on the attached link, you'll find necessary credentials for GCM:

[**link**](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gcm.html)

Comment: Thanks larryp! The attributes on table 1 are at the high level, I am interested to know what goes between the GCM client agent and the GCM server before returning the registration ID. I am trying to know if the registration ID is a derivative of these attributes. I think this probably requires a black box analysis.